# According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, taglib

Can someone please tell me why I am getting above error?
I have below code in JSP :

```
<c:set var="username" value="${cookie.username.value}" />
        <s:hidden key="appInfo.createdBy" value="${username}" />
```

For which I am getting above error.

I searched a lot on google and many replies said talked about JSTL tag whihc I already have in my tags as :

`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

And in web.xml I have :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
```

what am I missing here??

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am sorry I had added the code but I don't know how it was missing. I did edit the question with code. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of JSTL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

change <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %> is not right for me.
for my project(web-app version="3.0" )  IDE(MyEclipse)
I see the configuration file of x.tld.There is the false of select which do not allow the select apperance ${} or <%=%>.So I got a way to cheat in the web.xml.

1. `<jsp-config>
       <taglib>
           <taglib-uri>/huang</taglib-uri>
           <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/x.tld</taglib-location>
       </taglib>
   </jsp-config>`  add to web.xml
2. declare the new taglib-url name "huang" to my jsp file like this:

   `<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="/huang" %>`
3. to use`<x:out select="$casexml//案例//${node.name }" />`

   I can get the right result